# Initialize Objective-C tye in Objective-C++ class

Tags: objective-c++

I need to initialize an instance of an Objective-C SDK ("PortSIPSDK") like this:

```
sdkInstance = [[PortSIPSDK alloc] init];
```

However, I need to do this in an Objective-C++ class, and xcode complains about the above line of code:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PortSIPSDK", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libCore-d.a(CSIPClientIOSImpl.mm.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

"CSIPClientIOSImpl.mm" is the name of the file in which the class is implemented.

If I don't do that initialization, xcode doesn't complain, but an error happens when I try to call methods of that sdk instance, presumably because it was never initialized.

Comment: That's a linker error, not a compiler error. It means you probably forgot to include the binary code of the SDK in your project.

Comment: It can't be, because that's not the only call to the SDK I have. After the initialization I call other methods from the SDK. The linker error only happens if the initialization is there. It doesn't happen if I comment out the initialization and leave the other methods.

The other methods cause a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in that case, presumably because the sdk variable wasn't initialized.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "call to the SDK". But with a class, the only time you would link to something is link to the class object when you send a message to the class, like `[PortSIPSDK alloc]` here. If you don't send a message to the class, then you don't link to the class in the SDK, so you don't get a linker error. But of course if you don't initialize `sdkInstance`, then it will just be `nil` (assuming you are using ARC here), which is useless. Sending messages to `nil` will not crash, but if you access fields on `nil` using `->`, that will crash.

Comment: Anyway, at the end of the day, the problem is that you don't have the binary code for the `PortSIPSDK` class, for whatever reason (either you didn't compile it as part of this build, or you didn't include a pre-built library, or something).

Comment: By "call to the sdk" I meant doing something like [sdkIntance sdkMethod: parameter]. xcode doesn't complain about this.

Also, it doesn't complain when I declare the variable. It only complains for the initialization.

Comment: Yes, because in none of those cases are you linking to anything.